# sql server If statement and output count hits

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, if-statement

This is the scenario If Hit > 0 SQL server should return false and update a table. I have problems with the syntax.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckTransactionExist_TransID]

@TransID int

AS

Declare @Hits bit
Declare @Hit bigint

SET @Hit = 0


Select @Hit = @Hit + count(1)  From tblBooking Where (TransID = @TransID)
Select @Hit = @Hit + count(1)  From tblOrders Where (TransID = @TransID) 
Select @Hit = @Hit + count(1)  From tblTransaction_DP Where (TransID = @TransID)


if @Hit > 0 then
    begin
        @Hits = True
    end
else
    begin
        @Hits = False
        update tblTransaction set isVoid = 1 where (Transid = @TransID)
    end

Select @Hits
```

I have these errors: incorrect syntax near the keyword then and select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire body can be replaced with:

```
if exists(select * from tblBooking Where TransID = @TransID)
  or exists(select * from tblOrders where TransID = @TransID)
  or exists(select * from tblTransaction_DP Where TransID = @TransID)
begin
    select 1
end
else
begin
    update tblTransaction set isVoid = 1 where (Transid = @TransID)
    select 0
end
```

Notes:

- Don't *count* the number of rows if all that you care about is whether rows [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or not
- there's no `then` in T-SQL's [`if` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- There's no boolean [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in SQL Server, so no boolean literals like `true` or `false`
- You shouldn't name your stored procedures starting with `sp_`; that prefix is [reserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187926%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for Microsoft's **System** Procedures. If MS add a system procedure to the `master` database with the same name as one of yours, the system procedure will be used instead of yours:

> We strongly recommend that you not use the prefix **sp_** in the procedure name. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system stored procedures. For more information, see [Creating Stored Procedures (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190669%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

- If the data type of the returned value matters, you can replace `select 0` with `select CONVERT(bit,0)`, and `select 1` with `select CONVERT(bit,1)`. There's no shorthand for specifying a bit literal.
- If you want to set a variable's value, you have to use a [`SET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189484%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) statement (or a `SELECT`). You can't just assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckTransactionExist_TransID]

@TransID INT

AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.tblBooking 
        WHERE TransID = @TransID

        UNION

        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.tblOrders 
        WHERE TransID = @TransID

        UNION

        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.tblTransaction_DP 
        WHERE TransID = @TransID
    ) BEGIN

        RETURN 1

    END
    ELSE BEGIN

        UPDATE dbo.tblTransaction 
        SET isVoid = 1 
        WHERE Transid = @TransID

        RETURN 0

    END

END
```